# How to fix error with Network Solutions ssl proxy

Tags: php, javascript, http, ssl, joomla

I am having a problem with Network Solutions using a proxy ssl I am using a Joomla 2.5 CMS http://www.networksolutions.com/support/ssl-redirects/ 
In this article they have some JavaScript

```
<script language="javascript">
if (document.location.protocol != "https:")
{
document.location.href = "https://subdomain.yourdomain.com" + document.location.pathname;
};
</script>
```

When every i try and use this code it only forces the page that you are on to go to ssl not all the links to other pages. So it brakes the page. What I would like to be able to do is force some pages to be over ssl. Is this possible or do i have to force the hole site to be over ssl. I know i could rewrite the template so that it calls everything over ssl but it seems like this would be more work then it would be worth. Any input would be great!
Thank you,
Justin

Sorry needed to point out one more think if you go to the link above it says that because Network solutions is using a proxy ssl you can't use php to detect if its over ssl witch means when ever you tern on force ssl in the contrail panel the hole site just loops.

Comment: If you want to access your whole site under ssl than there is an option in global config->server->force ssl.

Comment: Sorry i should have explaned a little better when ever i use force ssl the hole website loops because i am unable to detect ssl using $_SERVER['HTTPS'] i also have tried detecting the port $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] if you go to that link it says that you can't use server side code to detect ssl.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use that JavaScript. Just link to `https://subdomain.yourdomain.com/page-your-are-linking-to/` whenever you want SSL support. That's what the script is doing anyway.